# How to troubleshoot wayland mouse+keyboard settings? (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, 22.04, wayland, libinput

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 recently, from 21.10, and ran into the same problem I had since ubuntu introduced wayland by default: my touchpad and keyboard do not work on wayland.
I have an Asus laptop with touchpad, keyboard and touchscreen. Wayland actually recognises the touchscreen, so I can get past GDM by typing my password with the screen (and chosing Xorg as a session). However, as I feel Xorg will be deprecated soon and I do not see any fix, I need your help to get my input devices working on wayland.

I tried installing `libinput-tools` and looking at the recognised devices, where I do see my touchpad and keyboard. Also, running `libinput debug-events` does show pad, mouse, keyboard.

I do not seem to find documentation on how to look into the process of device recognition by wayland (especially not for the GDM login screen), and I admit it is difficult to troubleshoot from wayland using only touchscreen...

Happy to have some clues on how to gather more info and file a proper bug report.

Needless to say, all input devices work perfectly under Xorg, so no hardware nor kernel issue.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue in the meantime?

Comment: Thanks for asking, Akito, but no, I have not resolved it. I am using my touchscreen for the login screen on wayland and then open an Xorg session. But it keeps annoying me, and I am worried about the moment when Xorg will be finally phased out and no other solution than wayland is available.
(sorry, I am the initial author, but there are too many login options, so I chose launchpad instead of something else)

Comment: Hmmm.  You seem to have created two accounts, which means you aren't able to reply to comments on your own question above.  Please log out of the @PhilippeSeidel account and log back in as 'Ph Sei' under which you posted the question.

Comment: You'll then be able to reply to the above comment.  But unfortunately this is "not an answer" and will likely be removed (unless a mod can move it to a comment).

Comment: It seems that you have had both of these accounts for a number of years, but with no real activity on either.  You may want to merge them, but it would probably be easier to just delete one of them.